# In spring, how to simplify multi annotations into one

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

for ex, I wanna simpilify following code(I use kotlin code)

```
@GetMapping("/test-get")
@ResponseBody
fun testGet(): String {
    return "test get"
}
```

to

```
@GetJson("/test-get")
fun testGet(): String {
    return "test get"
}
```

how to impl GetJson annotation

Comment: this is a very opinion based question, since **simplify** is a very vague term. each annotation has a certain meaning. of course some are optional and can be skipped. they work as instruction for machines as well for humans - annotations can help people to understand code better

Comment: If your controller is annotated with `@RestController` you only need the `@GetMapping`. In fact `@GetJson` is misleading as depending on what is requested by the client it could be plain text, xml, or whatever it requests. So it doesn't necessarily have to be json.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simplify multiple annotations into one then you can create a custom annotation that handles both @GetMapping and @ResponseBody annotations in your case. So here is an example of how you can define your @GetJson annotation that handles both annotations:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public @interface GetJson {
    String value();
}
```

after this definition,in your Kotlin code, you can use the `@GetJson` annotation instead of the `@GetMapping` and `@ResponseBody` annotations:

```
@GetJson("/test-get")
fun testGet(): String {
    return "test get"
}
```

but make sure that the `@GetJson` annotation is `scanned` by Spring so that it can be used to configure the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

@Stack Clone need to provide additional explanation

it should use @AliasFor redirect custom annotation attr to builtin annotation attr, for ex following is my @Get impl

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.GET])
annotation class Get(
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.name].
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    val name: String = "",
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.value].
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    vararg val value: String = [],
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.path].
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    val path: Array<String> = [],
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.params].
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    val params: Array<String> = [],
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.headers].
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    val headers: Array<String> = [],
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.consumes].
     * @since 4.3.5
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    val consumes: Array<String> = [],
    /**
     * Alias for [RequestMapping.produces].
     */
    @get:AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping::class)
    val produces: Array<String> = []
)
```